# Image to spin 180 deg?

Tags: css, image

I am just a beginner, so I really don't know how to do much of this CSS styling.

I need to make this (gif) [image] to spin in 180 deg, but I can't seem to get it working.

Here is my HTML:

```
<header>
    <h1><img src="pictures/accent.gif" alt="accent"  />Tomatoes are Fruit!</h1>
```

I have tried this CSS:

`accent {transform: rotate(180deg);}`

I tried changing `accent` to `accent.gif` and `#accent` and `h1 accent` but it's not working, so I am not sure if that's what I am getting wrong or the style. Again very new at this!

edit:Sorry I just added the picture. I added the class and it's still not working. I guess once it's correctly formatted the little orange line looks like it's spinning.

Comment: please edit your question and add your gif and modified description

Answer (score 1):

You should add **Class** selector to your CSS and HTML. In your code your are mentioning `alt` attribute which is used for alternative text when image not showing and not intended to use in CSS.

```css
.accent {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    <img class="accent" src="https://placeimg.com/150/150/4" alt="accent" />Tomatoes are Fruit!
  </h1>
</header>
```